# How HTTP proxy should handle HEAD requests?

Tags: http, proxy

HTTP/1.1 protocol as stated in RFC7230 is stateless but the HEAD request method should generate some state on client side and in proxies as there is no other way to determine the length of message body of response to HEAD request.

There is only a couple of ways to determine the actual transfer length of HTTP response. They are described in 3.3.3 of RFC7230.

Let us assume that the HTTP request piplining is in action and client generates some valid sequence of HEAD and GET to some existing resources on origin server and there is a transparent HTTP proxy on path from client to origin server.

The HTTP protocol is defined as stateless so no state must be generated in any part of the communication or by any action taken by the protocol itself (not the transport protocol that must generate some state like TCP to reorder messages etc.).

How should the proxy identify the end of origin server response (a.e. the length of message body) to a client HEAD request if the fact that this request had been done must not be remembered by proxy (must not generate a state)?

If the proxy blindly interprets the Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding fields sent by the origin server in response to HEAD method it will block in waiting the message body indefinitely long as the origin server will never send the message body.

The client therefore must generate some state to remember that not a GET but a HEAD request was sent (because of the same issue - no way to determine message body length).

So the HEAD method is inherently a stateful one in stateless HTTP protocol and this is a contradiction.

And what makes the situation worse is that HEAD method must be implemented by any server as stated in 4.1 of RFC7231 and can not be responded with 501 or 405.

This contradiction makes it possible to implement the simple attack vector on HTTP proxy: flud the proxy with HEAD requests to generate enough state to make an out of memory error.

The small research that I have done indicates that modern proxies swaps the HEAD request to GET one but this will generate even more state and traffic  than the simple remembering of the resource path and request type (in some hash map for example).

Therefore I can conclude that the presence of HEAD request contradicts with the statelessness of HTTP/1.1 protocol.

Comment: Pesse explain why you think a HEAD request must generate a state in a proxy. Remember that HEAD requests don't generate a response body.

Comment: @CodeCaster it is exactly explained in question description

Comment: It is unclear to me what "state" you mean. If a HEAD response contains a Content-Length header, then yes, a user agent (or proxy) will have remembered that the request was a HEAD request and that actually no body will follow. That's not "state".

Comment: @CodeCaster 'Stateless' means that any action taken by protocol must not produce any data to be handeled for some time (a.e. 'state'). But HEAD request requires to create some information about it and save it until the replay is arived (a.e. 'state')

Comment: Yes, and the TCP/IP stack remembers the "state" of the connection, otherwise the server couldn't reply. That's not the sort of state that HTTP's statelessness is about.

Answer (score 0):

The RFC states:

> HTTP is defined as a stateless protocol, meaning that each request
>      message can be understood in isolation.

This doesn't mean a server can't maintain any state whatsoever. It doesn't mean the server can't keep the request data in memory, or keep state about the TCP/IP connection or about the request itself - otherwise it wouldn't be able to respond.

It just means that there's no state to be preserved in between different request-response pairs.

Comment: So You agree that intermediary like a proxy should remember the type of the request stated by client to correctly identify the response length? Then what should happen in request pipelining case? BTW state of TCP connection or IP fragmantation is not a type of state managed by HTTP protocol so it do not count.